# Schedule Crontab for running PHP script

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to run PHP file on path `/var/www/html/rss_feed/mirror.php` through cron tabs. For this I performed the below steps.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then I edited the file by inserting the following code

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# avt 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /ar/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/rss_feed/nbt_times.php
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

As you can see below is the line of code inserted to schedule cron tab after every 2 minutes to run a php file.

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/rss_feed/nbt_times.php
```

I even tried following

```
2 * * * * lynx -dump http://192.168.0.232/rss_feed/mirror.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

and even this

```
2  * * * * /your/path/to/php /var/www/html/rss_feed/nbt_times.php
```

and many more formats from different articles.

The php script is not running. Do I need to put the code somewhere else? Or I am on the wrong way. Can you please help me find out what is the issue.

Comment: Check the error logs?

Comment: There is no entry even in the error log. I searched for mirror.php. But didn't get anything

Comment: run php file from command line - does it work?

Comment: No. It says Could not open file. I tried setting permissions to 777 but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It should work but need to get some clarifications here, file name seems to be different one time its mirror.php and another time its nbt_times.php

which php file has to run on the specific time that has to be specified. As you specified you're running /var/www/html/rss_feed/mirror.php then, then specify mirrror.php on your first command .

The 2nd and third command will run the job for 2nd minute of every hour. like (4:02,5:02,6:02, etc)

Try this crontab

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/rss_feed/mirror.php
```

This will run for every 2 mins hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try with php5-cli:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php5-cli -f /var/www/html/rss_feed/nbt_times.php
```

Also add write to logs and see them after minute:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/rss_feed/nbt_times.php >>log.log 2>>log.err
```

Check permissions of your php-file. Make 0777 for checking. Try create the simplest php file with one row and run it via cron.

Comment: /usr/bin/php is the cli version. Don't make it 777 just for checking, just run sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/php